# Sqoop incremental import (db schema incorrect)

Tags: hortonworks-data-platform, sqoop2

Im trying to do an incremental import using the Sanbox 2.1 and a Microsoft SQL Server (AdventureWorks database). For the incremental import i’m using the following command:

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.40.133:1434;database=AdventureWorksLT2012;username=test;password=test" --table ProductModel --hive-import --check-column ProductModelID --incremental append --last-value 128 -- --schema SalesLT
```

As you can see in the error message below, the select statement “SELECT MAX([SalesLT].[ProductModelID]) FROM ProductModel” is not constructed the right way.

The schema name is added to the column without the table name and the table name in the FROM clause is missing the schema name…

```
Warning: /usr/lib/sqoop/../accumulo does not exist! Accumulo imports will fail.
Please set $ACCUMULO_HOME to the root of your Accumulo installation.
14/06/24 07:05:33 INFO sqoop.Sqoop: Running Sqoop version: 1.4.4.2.1.1.0-385
14/06/24 07:05:33 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: Using Hive-specific delimiters for output. You can override
14/06/24 07:05:33 INFO tool.BaseSqoopTool: delimiters with --fields-terminated-by, etc.
14/06/24 07:05:33 INFO manager.SqlManager: Using default fetchSize of 1000
14/06/24 07:05:33 INFO manager.SQLServerManager: We will use schema SalesLT
14/06/24 07:05:33 INFO tool.CodeGenTool: Beginning code generation
14/06/24 07:05:34 INFO manager.SqlManager: Executing SQL statement: SELECT t.* FROM [SalesLT].[ProductModel] AS t WHERE 1=0
14/06/24 07:05:34 INFO orm.CompilationManager: HADOOP_MAPRED_HOME is /usr/lib/hadoop-mapreduce
Note: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/bcb9143989664ced51458e8a0dbd52b9/ProductModel.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
14/06/24 07:05:37 INFO orm.CompilationManager: Writing jar file: /tmp/sqoop-root/compile/bcb9143989664ced51458e8a0dbd52b9/ProductModel.jar
14/06/24 07:05:37 INFO tool.ImportTool: Maximal id query for free form incremental import: SELECT MAX([SalesLT].[ProductModelID]) FROM ProductModel
14/06/24 07:05:37 ERROR tool.ImportTool: Encountered IOException running import job: java.io.IOException: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Invalid object name 'ProductModel'.
```

Any help is appreciated.

Thank you!

PS.
Importing a full table is working fine.

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.40.133:1434;database=AdventureWorksLT2012;username=test;password=test" --table ProductModel --hive-import -- --schema SalesLT
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.40.133:1434;database=AdventureWorksLT2012;username=test;password=test" --table ProductModel --hive-import -- --schema SalesLT --incremental append --check-column ProductModelID --last-value "128"
```

Answer (score 0):

I think following command will work..

```
sqoop import --connect "jdbc:sqlserver://192.168.40.133:1434;database=AdventureWorksLT2012;username=test;password=test" --table ProductModel --hive-import --incremental append --check-column ProductModelID --last-value "128" -- --schema SalesLT
```